# Define static DCOM port

Tags: firewall, wmi, dcom

We have a monitoring server that needs to monitor a Windows Server 2016 in a different VLAN. These VLANS are separated by a hardware firewall.

Instead of opening a range of ports for the DCOM communication we would like to set **one static** port.

The Windows firewall on the servers are turned off.

The guides below do not seem to work:

https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-be/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/setting-up-a-fixed-port-for-wmi

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1559.how-to-configure-a-static-dcom-port-for-ad-cs.aspx

Does someone have an idea how to set a static DCOM port on Windows Server 2016?

Comment: I have the same issue also on MS Windows Server 2016. I used dcomcnfg to set the static endpoint port number and verified it in the registry, rebooted, but it is still using a random port. Did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The CA will not change listening ports until the first certificate request comes in, so do not expect that you will see the port change in NETSTAT or other tools until that happens.

> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1559.how-to-configure-a-static-dcom-port-for-ad-cs.aspx